# Jquery thinks table is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please consider the following code:

**CODE**:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#add_new_item_ingredient", function() {
  $(this).siblings("#ingredients_table").append('<tr><td style="width:20%"> <input type="text" id="option_item_costs_2" class="form-control" placeholder="£2.50"> </td><td style="width:50%"> <input type="text" id="option_item_desc_2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex. Extra tomato"> <input type="hidden" id="option_item_id_2" value="-1"> </td></tr>');
});

$(document).on("click", "#remove_new_item_ingredient", function() {
  $(this).siblings("#ingredients_table tr").each(function(index) {
    alert("!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped notifications" id="ingredients_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <tr>..</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn_1" id="add_new_item_ingredient">+ Ingredient</button>
<button class="btn_1" style="background:#C70000;" id="remove_new_item_ingredient">- Ingredient</button>
```

Adding new rows with the first button works great, however when I attempt to remove the last `tr` element from the same table, it does nothing. I am now attempting to alert, for each `tr` element found, but I get no alerts. I have tried getting the table row count which always returns 0, and also attempted trying to get the element with `#ingredients_table >tbody >tr`

I can confirm that both of the click events are firing correctly, and I can correctly select the table element, just none of the rows within.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using this: `$(this).siblings("#ingredients_table")`. Just `$("#ingredients_table")` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the button `#remove_new_item_ingredient`has no `tr` siblings.

You either select the table first and then use `find` to get the `tr`'s:

```
$(this).siblings("#ingredients_table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
```

or use the:

```
$("#ingredients_table tr").each(function(index) {
```

which is better in redability.

And as @T.J.Crowder mentioned:

1. You have two `tbody` elements in your table (neither of them closed, probably a typo)
2. You're appending the rows to the `table`, not the `tbody`

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. I fixed it by accident in my answer, but was still wondering **why** the OP's code wasn't finding the `tr`s... Of course it's because of the `siblings` thing.

Comment: I suggest grabbing anything else from my answer you like into yours; I'll delete mine (since I know you can see it even if deleted :-) ).

Comment: Perfect solved the issue (apologies for the unclosed tbody, that was just an issue with my typing up the question) Appreciate it chaps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove's handler `$.siblings` looks for `tr` elements on the same level as button, which is not the case. `tr`s are in table, that is 2 levels down. So just modify your call to `$(this).siblings("#ingredients_table").find('tr')`